# IN clause usage for DATE fields in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

I need to select those rows from a table which has the value of a date column matching either of 3 different values. Can I do it using `IN` clause?

Example

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_name
WHERE Req_Date IN ('2014-01-12','2014-02-14','2014-03-17')
```

Will this work? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes with a small modification to have proper date literal.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE Date(Req_Date) IN (DATE '2014-01-12', DATE '2014-02-14', DATE '2014-03-17');
```

Comment: Trunc(Req_Date) is sometimes needed to zero the time elements..(if non zero)

Comment: @OracleUser: good point. I work in Teradata and date data type doesnt have timepart. I am updating the answer.

Comment: `date()` in Oracle is not a function, it's a datatype. You may have meant `to_date()`, but that is only needed if the column is not a `data` datatype. If it is a `date` datatype then `trunc()` would remove the time component from the date so the column matches your parameters.

Comment: Yes you are right about to_date() .. And As the question states.. It is a date column.